who is configuring my network interfaces in lubuntu noble
After my release upgrade from jammy to noble my wlan is not longer auto connect to router.
As far I read netplan is managing now network interfaces. But why does wlan connect after I restart all NetworkManager systemd services after login?
nmcli device 
DEVICE         TYPE      STATE                   CONNECTION 
wlan0          wifi      connected               daheim     
lo             loopback  connected (externally)  lo         
p2p-dev-wlan0  wifi-p2p  disconnected            --         
eth0           ethernet  unavailable             --  

and
networkctl 
IDX LINK  TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP    
  1 lo    loopback carrier     unmanaged
  2 eth0  ether    no-carrier  unmanaged
  3 wlan0 wlan     routable    unmanaged

    namei /etc/resolv.conf 

    f: /etc/resolv.conf
     d /
     d etc
     l resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
       d ..
       d run
       d systemd
       d resolve
       - stub-resolv.conf

the yaml file for wlan
sudo cat /etc/netplan/90-NM-fffdced1-8475-45b4-8b10-38f04c8df9f5.yaml 
[sudo] password for alex: 
network:
  version: 2
  wifis:
    NM-fffdced1-8475-45b4-8b10-38f04c8df9f5:
      renderer: NetworkManager
      match: {}
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
      ipv6-address-generation: "stable-privacy"
      access-points:
        "PYUR 00DBA":
          auth:
            key-management: "psk"
            password: "to secret"
          networkmanager:
            uuid: "fffdced1-8475-45b4-8b10-38f04c8df9f5"
            name: "daheim"
            passthrough:
              connection.autoconnect-priority: "20"
              connection.timestamp: "1725038794"
              ipv4.may-fail: "false"
              ipv6.ip6-privacy: "-1"
              proxy._: ""
      networkmanager:
        uuid: "fffdced1-8475-45b4-8b10-38f04c8df9f5"
        name: "daheim"

I'm totally confused now. Any insight would be nice.


I finally found out why the autoconnection from my wlan was not reliable working on my system.
It was a timming problem caused by an old long forgotten own created udev rule (I erased it).
After climbing down my rabbit whole I found this.
wpa_supplicant[: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-95 

And I set my region to germany/deutschland (not sure if this was really necessary)
cat /etc/modprobe.d/cfg80211.conf 
# Versuch region domain für netz zusetzten.

options cfg80211 ieee80211_regdom=DE

I found this here
And to answer it correct it is networkmanger who handles my connection.

Thanks for sharing your solution :-)

In my case the file in /etc/netplan are changed when I change it from something like nm-applet
When I unchecked the connect automatically

the file was changed to
network:
  version: 2
  wifis:
    NM-a5806190-1854-4710-b0e8-551b35228a95:
      renderer: NetworkManager
      match:
        name: "wlp15s0"
        macaddress: "10:6F:D9:75:43:AD"
      macaddress: "preserve"
      ipv6-address-generation: "stable-privacy"
      access-points:
        "pi.hole":
          auth:
            key-management: "psk"
            password: "xxxxxxxxxxx"
          mode: "ap"
          networkmanager:
            uuid: "a5806190-1854-4710-b0e8-551b35228a95"
            name: "hotspot"
            passthrough:
              connection.autoconnect: "false"
              connection.timestamp: "1734348097"
              ipv6.method: "shared"
              ipv6.ip6-privacy: "-1"
              proxy._: ""
      networkmanager:
        uuid: "a5806190-1854-4710-b0e8-551b35228a95"
        name: "hotspot"

The renderer: NetworkManager part mentions that in my case it is managed by the network manager
$ sudo systemctl status NetworkManager.service
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-12-16 13:59:11 IST; 3h 0min ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
   Main PID: 2764 (NetworkManager)

also has related line for this interface
Dec 16 16:52:52 builder NetworkManager[2764]: <info>  [1734348172.5548] audit: op="connection-update" uuid="a5806190-1854-4710-b0e8-551b35228a95" name="hotspot" args="connection.autoconnect,connection.timestamp" p>

So If you want to change the autoconnect behaviour - change to include
connection.autoconnect: "false"

for your interface of choice - or just use something graphical like nm-applet

I use nm-tray and I checked with nmcli that connection is set to auto connect. connection.autoconnect:                 yes the frustpart is sometimes it connects and sometimes not. I try to alter my yaml file and check it out. Thank you.
